# jquery datetimepicker minDate on radio button change

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datetime, datepicker

I have this script http://jsfiddle.net/Kj55E/6/

I am using datetimepicker plugin

I have following issue: exp_date minDate has to be begin_date + 1 . Everything works OK on first run. But after I change begin_date ... minDate for exp_date don't refresh... Please help

Thank you 
Coscho

Comment: why are your datepicker fields `display:none`? What happens if you let them be visible?

Comment: is a span <exp_date_span> not datepicker fields. that span shows on auction radio click

Comment: It appears that begin_date defaults to the current date and immediately sets the default exp_date. This occurs before the user has selected any date.  Even the *first* user-selected begin-date has no effect on exp_date. I would say that you need an exp_date updater function that fires after the begin_date **updates** or on begin_date.datepicker close/lose focus.

Comment: Yes you right. I fixed that adding KingKongFrog suggestion , and $('#exp_date').val(''); $('#begin_date').val(''); on "normal sell" change event. Thank you. here is working code http://jsfiddle.net/Kj55E/22/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of initiating with click, try putting all your logic in the onClose event of #begin_date

The end_date is being initiated on click...not on selection.

```
        $('#begin_date').datetimepicker({
            showSecond : true,
            dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd',
            timeFormat : 'hh:mm:ss',
            stepMinute : 5,
            stepSecond : 5,
            minDate: 1,
            onClose: function () {
                test = $("#begin_date").datetimepicker('getDate');
                testm = new Date(test.getTime());
                testm.setDate(testm.getDate() + 1);

                $("#exp_date").datetimepicker("option", "minDate", testm);
                $("#exp_date").datetimepicker('setDate', testm );
            }
```